# How to trigger url in backend (without opening any browser) IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework

I am developing an IONIC project on iot relay switch. ( any help will be appreciated)
Whenever i am triggering a url, either it is opening in same app or launching a new browser.
but my need is that, it should trigger a url but it should not open anywhere.

I have a basic code like this:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-title>
IOT Project
</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<h3 text-center> Basic Switch </h3>
<hr>
<p>
<a href="http://192.168.1.5/gpio?state_12=0" target = nobrowser>switch On</a><br><br>
<a href="http://192.168.1.5/gpio?state_12=1" target = nobrowser>switch Off</a>
</p>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTP for this. If just want to hit the url, try this.

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="call(0)">switch On</button> 
<button (click)="call(1)">switch Off</button>
```

**TS**

```
 call(id) { 
     this.http.get(`http://192.168.1.5/gpio?state_12=${id}`); 
 }
```

Comment: Yes, M using IONIC,  It is triggering the URL but also opening the browser, but i dont want to open it in browser, it should run background